# How automatically create SQL Server relationship diagram?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I am new to SQL Server. On the previous job I used working with Postgres and MySQL. But now I was faced with the task connected with SQL Server. And I discovered very strange thing in the DB with that I should work. There don't exist any relations!

Is it normal to SQL Server? How can I automatically connect tables according to their primary keys? Any other ideas?

An screenshot of the ER diagram:

[image]

Comment: Like other most other DBMS products, foreign key relationships in SQL Server are optional, although a best practice. It is the responsibility of the developer or DBA to create them. Some modeling tools can auto-detect possible relationships based on defined primary keys and column naming conventions. It may help of you mention the tool you are using to create the ERD.

Comment: Thanks for reply! I am using MS SQL server Management studio, also I have already tried DBVisualizer. Do you have anysuggestions for them?

Comment: Have you tried Database Diagram option available in SSMS?

Comment: @Vicky Yes,  it shows all tables without relations between them

Comment: An exaple of tables from DB diagram, that really do have relations:http://imgur.com/a/oTvVL

Comment: It is *normal* for sloppy programmers to just slap together a ton of tables and not care/worry/think about relationships at all ..... but this is definitely **NOT** a SQL Server / product-specific flaw - more a human flaw

Comment: If the database's creator didn't create any foreign keys, there aren't any relations to display. If the database creator didn't create any relations at all, and thought that 3-letter table names are a good idea **[redacted due to SO propriety rules]**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are talking about creating hundreds of FKs you may be better off by just adding those relationships manually either through SSMS database diagram or through a sql script.
If the number of possible relations is really large or you expect to have to do this again in the future, you may want to look to SMO (SQL Management Objects) and either use Powershell or a small C# program to script out the tsql that would join those tables. But you would need to make sure that there is a repeatable pattern / naming convention between the columns and tables that you can leverage. For Example:

```
Table1
ID
Name
```

```
Table2
ID
Table1ID
Name
```

Here you could consider Table1ID as a FK referencing Table1.ID